# firefox font rendering problem/issue

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts, safari, rendering

maybe anyone have an idea **why** this is happening **and how to fix** it ?

[image]

```
p  
{ 
   display: block; 
   margin: 1em 0px;
}

p.description 
{
   color: #969797;
   font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: lighter;
   letter-spacing: -0.05em;
   line-height: 1em;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: none;
   text-transform: none;
   word-spacing: 0em;
}
```

Comment: You could try using Firebug's and Chrome's inspect element to check the computed CSS styles are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean why FF displays things bold?

I'd have to see your code i suppose...

Special characters, though, are usually a bit tricky. If your character encoding type is not set right, or the visitor has the right font not installed, the browser may just pick another font that looks like it.

The difference between the browsers is caused by Webkit (at least so I think).

Comment: There was my mistake... in the html one place I've opened <b> and it ended with <b>.. stupid missing "\" :) "Special characters, though, are usually a bit tricky" <- helped.

Answer (score 0):

Safari and Chrome use Webkit, maybe that's it...

Comment: I'm not using any specific stuff for -webkit, either -moz, everything looks the same, except font rendering, which makes me crazy...

Comment: that's not what I meant, I mean font rendering differences between webkit and gecko engine... see this: http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/